# HTML div from behind shouldn't be detected but must be in front with CSS position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, css-position

### Description

I have a `div` with a table, which each TD of this table will have an event `onClick`.

But sometimes, I will need to show some texts in front of this table, eventhough, this text can not mess my table's TDs.

So my problem is, I need to show a text in front of a table, but when I click on this text, it will not affect anything, and the correct clicked TD behind the text should call its event.

### What I have done:

I have `#div1` and `#div2`, `#div1` is behind, `#div2` is the front (both are `position:absolute`).

So, `#div1` is there, but it's *invisible*, only `#div2` is shown.

Eventhough, only `#div2` is being shown, I need to show the text from `#div1` in front of `#div2`.
In order to make this, I put a `span` on `#div1` and set span's `z-index:1`.
This way, `#div1` is still not appearing, but its `span` is.

Everything is OK, but I got a new problem now.

I need to click on `#div2` (the front), and get the event on the whole div.

Even if there is a text from `#div1`, it shouldn't have bussiness there, just be showed.

It's hard to understand just reading, so I made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9jy5/7/).

Click on the red "Text1 from #div1...", I need it to alert the TD html content!

Comment: @DavidThomas I need to alert only div2, even if I click on "Text1", it should alert "#div2"

Comment: @DavidThomas I edited, please have a read. Thanks!

Comment: You can’t "ignore" elements in a click event. If the click happens on the text, you need to either be able to trace the TD in the bubbling phase (make the span a descendant), delegate the event or attach multiple listeners.

Comment: @David please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/W9jy5/7/ Sorry, wrong link, now it's correct.

Comment: ok, but how is that a reply to my comment?

Comment: @David I sent the wrong link, did you see the right one? The 7th update

Comment: yes I saw it, but I don’t know if we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the click "fall-through" the `#div1 span1` with some CSS:

```
#div1 span{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

It should work in FF and webkit browsers, but you're out of luck with IE8 and lower.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/W9jy5/12/

Comment: It's browser compatibility is not good. For IE and Opera it works only for SVG.

Comment: @MinkoGechev Indeed, that's the drawback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/W9jy5/5/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").click(function(){
        clickedOnDiv2();
    });
    $('#span1').click(function (e) {
        var div2 = $('#div2'),
            offset = div2.offset();
        if (e.pageX > offset.left && e.pageX < offset.left + div2.width() &&
            e.pageY > offset.top && e.pageY < offset.top + div2.height()) {
                clickedOnDiv2();
            }
    });

    function clickedOnDiv2() {
        alert('#div2');
    }
})​
```

In this workaround there's a click event listener on the span element. If the user click on Text1 and the click is over #div2 we execute `clickOnDiv2`.

And here it answer for the question in your comment http://jsfiddle.net/W9jy5/17/.
It's cross-browser.

Comment: Yes it will, but you have to add the event listeners using `on`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `#div1` and `#div2` are DOM siblings, you can’t "capture" the events of `#div1` in `#div2`. And since the `SPAN` is a descendant to `#div1`, but you still want the same handler as you attached to `#div2`, you need to attach the listener on multiple elements or rearrange the DOM.

One way to solve this is to delegate the click to a parent div instead:

```
$("#container").on('click', '#div2, #div1 span', function(){
    alert("#div2");
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pwkqq/

Comment: This won't handle cases in which the span with Text1 isn't over the #div2.

Comment: @MinkoGechev you mean "over" as in z-indexed over?